# Checked baggages held in Minneapolis Airport Customs - not sure what to do?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, msp, delta-air-lines

We have returned from a family vacation in Europe on Aug 1st
CDG->MSP->SEA

We picked up our bags at MSP, went through border control and put them back on the Delta conveyor belt before taking our MSP->SEA

At SEA, we didn’t have our luggage, so I filed a missing luggage claim with Delta

Today is Aug 4th and I haven’t heard anything. I call the delta baggage service twice a day and they tell me the same things:

- Baggage are in Customs. They got randomly pulled for additional checks but did not get released as of Aug 4th
- They cannot get in touch with MSP on the phone
- Nothing they can do
- They say the delay is very unusual

We don’t  have anything special in our baggage that would trigger any concerns (used clothes, everyday medication in prescription bottle, etc).

Is there anything I can do beyond waiting and calling?

Comment: Were the bags correctly tagged to their final destination?

Comment: Yes. They were tagged all the way to SEA ( I doubled checked that in CDG)

Comment: This sounds unlikely. If Customs was interested in your bag, they would have flagged it so you would have gone through those additional customs checks right there after baggage claim. Allowing it to clear customs and then pulling it again just isn't done except possibly in the most extraordinary circumstances. Something extraordinary like "we accidentally let 50 pounds of cocaine through". My guess is Delta or the airport lost it and doesn't want to admit it. That said, you could call MSP airport's lost luggage and customs offices yourself. I'm not sure how far that would get you though.

Comment: Michael: I called airfrance and asked them to look into my file. I got a slightly different information. 4/5 baggages made it to MSP according to their system and 1/5 baggage did not get scanned arriving at MSP. However, I picked up the 5 luggage at MSP to go through customs and rechecked them in. My files shows that delta has sent messages to CDG and MSP to see if my luggage are there.  I tried to find a number for MSP but none of them handle lost checked luggage.

Comment: Try +1-612-726-5141.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will try tomorrow. It is technically the number for non-checked baggage but it won't hurt to call.

Comment: I finally got the luggage today. It turned out that they were in SEA the whole time. The initial MSP -> SEA was supposed to be with Alaska Airlines but when we got to MSP, we got rebooked to another Delta flight to go to SEA and they didn’t change the baggage tags. Alaska has the luggage in SEA and we filed the claim with Delta. Since their system don’t talk to each other, Delta could not figure out where the bagages were. Finally Alaska called us Mon. Aug 5th saying they had luggages for us but no missing bag claim. We explained we had one with Delta, so they dropped off the luggage to Delta

Comment: Then Delta dropped the luggage at our house. I called Delta twice a day when the baggage were lost and twice a day I would get a different answer: taken by customs, telling us we forgot them in MSP, etc.